# Angular. How to inject ui.select into directive, that using xeditable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable, ui-select

I'm using xeditable and ui.select. I need to configure select with search for working with xeditable. So, I created directive:

```
var xeditable = angular.module('xeditable');

xeditable.directive('editableUiSelect', ['editableDirectiveFactory', 'editableNgOptionsParser',
        function(editableDirectiveFactory, editableNgOptionsParser) {
            return editableDirectiveFactory({
                directiveName: 'editableUiSelect',
                inputTpl: '<span></span>',
                render: function() {
                    this.parent.render.call(this);
                    var parsed = editableNgOptionsParser(this.attrs.eNgOptions);
                    var filter = " | filter: $select.search";
                    var html = "<ui-select ng-model='"+parsed.ngModel+"'>"+ 
                        "<ui-select-match>"+ "<span ng-bind='"+$select.selected.name+"'></span></ui-select-match>"+
                        "<ui-select-choices repeat='"+parsed.ngRepeat+filter+"'>"+"<span ng-bind='"+parsed.locals.displayFn+"'></span>"+
                        "</ui-select-choices></ui-select>";

                    this.inputEl.removeAttr('ng-model');
                    this.inputEl.removeAttr('ng-options');
                    this.inputEl.html(html);
                },
                autosubmit: function() {
                    // do smth
                }
            });
        }]);
```

This not work, because $select not found. `$select` is `uiSelectCtrl` controller, that using in `uiSelect` directive.

It seems, I need to inject `ui.select` into my directive, but I have no idea, how to do this and keep current xeditable instance.

**Question:** how can I inject `ui.select` or only `$select` controller into my directive?

If details I provided not enough, please, let me know.

**Solved.** I changed my directive code according to @jusopi answer and wrapped `$select` and `$parent.data` into quotes and all became working:

```
var Dashboard = angular.module('Dashboard');

Dashboard.directive('editableUiSelect', ['editableDirectiveFactory', 'editableNgOptionsParser',
        function(editableDirectiveFactory, editableNgOptionsParser) {
            return editableDirectiveFactory({
                directiveName: 'editableUiSelect',
                inputTpl: '<span></span>',
                render: function() {
                    this.parent.render.call(this);
                    var parsed = editableNgOptionsParser(this.attrs.eNgOptions);
                    var filter = " | filter: $select.search";
                    var html = "<ui-select ng-model='$parent.data'>"+ 
                        "<ui-select-match>"+ "<span ng-bind='$select.selected.name'></span></ui-select-match>"+
                        "<ui-select-choices repeat='"+parsed.ngRepeat+filter+"'>"+"<span ng-bind='"+parsed.locals.displayFn+"'></span>"+
                        "</ui-select-choices></ui-select>";

                    this.inputEl.removeAttr('ng-model');
                    this.inputEl.removeAttr('ng-options');
                    this.inputEl.html(html);
                },
                autosubmit: function() {
                    // do smth
                }
            });
        }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This makes the assumption that your problem is because you're not properly injecting module dependencies (as pointed out by @uday).*

To my knowledge you don't/can't add additional modular dependencies to an existing module.  The following would overwrite the `xeditable` module defined by your external lib because this syntax **defines** a module (as opposed to getting a module to define additional injectable constructs).

```
angular.module( <name>, <other-modules-array> )
```

Instead you need to define your directive in your own module, making sure to reference your `xeditable` and `ui.select` modules like so:

```
angular.module( 'myApp', [ 'xeditable', 'ui.select' ])
.directive( 'editableUiSelect', [ 
    'editableDirectiveFactory', 
    'editableNgOptionsParser',
    function( editableDirectiveFactory, editableNgOptionsParser ) { 
        ...
    }
])
```

Comment: thanks for answer! very good idea, I tried to add directive to my main module, that have all dependencies (like `xeditable` and `ui.select`), but I still have error "$select is not defined". `$select` is alias for `uiSelectCtrl`, as you can see here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/dist/select.js#L805 . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In other words, I need to use `uiSelect` directive in my own directive (see `var html`), but it seems that $select is not rendered yet.

Comment: I have solved this and added working example to my edited question. Thanks a lot for help !

Answer (score 0):

You can you dependency injection like this
var xeditable = angular.module('xeditable',['ui.select']);

Now ui.select will be available in xeditable.

Comment: `angular.module( 'xeditable', ['ui.select'] )` will overwrite the existing `xeditable` module.  It looks like OP is trying to add to the existing module, not define it.  Did you mean `angular.module( 'editableUiSelect', ['ui.select'] )`?

Comment: @jusopi yes, I trying to add ui.select to the existing module!